# sorting and removing duplicates from a vector<vectors< double> >

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, floating-point

Hello I'm aware there are a few similar questions to this but I haven't been able to solve my problem. 
I need to generate a unique set of points on a sphere in cartesian co-ordinates i.e. transform from spherical to cartesian. When I do this I store the points in a vector of vectors. However some duplicates are created and to remove them I have tried used the sort erase and unique functions. The problem is that sort doesn't see to sort my entire vector and I don't understand why? It works fine for a vector of vectors I just push back numbers into, just not for the vector of vectors generated by my cartesian function. I know this is simple I've been stuck for 3 days now and I'm sure it's staring me in the face!!! code and output are below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
  std::vector<double> locations;    //center of the bubble
  locations.push_back(1.0);
  locations.push_back(1.0);
  locations.push_back(1.0);
  std::vector<std::vector<double> > points;   //set of points to be created around the bubble
  double PI=atan(1)*4;

 for(int dr=1; dr<2; dr++){
     for (int phi=0; phi<180; phi+=90){
         for (int theta=0; theta<360; theta+=90){

             std::vector<double>  row;
             double x=locations[0]+(dr*sin(theta*(PI/180))*cos(phi*(PI/180)));
             double y=locations[1]+(dr*cos(theta*(PI/180)));
             double z=locations[2]+(dr*sin(theta*(PI/180))*sin(phi*(PI/180)));
             row.push_back(x);
             row.push_back(y);
             row.push_back(z);

             points.push_back(row);


         }
     }
 }



std::sort(points.begin(), points.end());    //sort points
std::cout<<"sorted points \n";
for (int i =0; i<points.size(); i++){
    std::cout<<points[i][0]<<" "<<points[i][1]<<" "<<points[i][2]<<"\n";
}

points.erase(std::unique(points.begin(), points.end()), points.end());  //erase duplicates

 std::cout<<"duplicates removed \n";
 for (int i =0; i<points.size(); i++){
    std::cout<< points[i][0]<<" "<<points[i][1]<<" "<<points[i][2]<<"\n";
}
```

}

OUTPUT

```
sorted points 
0 1 1
1 1 0
1 0 1         THIS HASN'T BEEN SORTED CORRECTLY
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 2 1
1 0 1          THIS HASN'T BEEN SORTED CORRECTLY
2 1 1
duplicates removed 
0 1 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 0 1
2 1 1
```

Comment: Yes, floating-point comparisons are a pain.

Comment: `for(int dr=1; dr<2; dr++)` you don't need a loop for it. You only need `const int dr = 1;`.

Comment: I would suggest making a class/struct that encapsulates the aspect of a point.  Then you can overload operators to make sorting and comparisons.  This will make it easier to see what you are attempting to do.

Comment: What sense do you put in this comparison? How did you tell that `1 0 1 THIS HASN'T BEEN SORTED CORRECTLY`? How do points `{0,1,1}`, `{1,1,0}`, `{1,0,1}` is less or greater than each other? How do compiler knows what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestions I realise I don't need the dr loop in this example but this is just the most simple version so the problem is clear. In the final code I need 3 dr steps and points every 10degrees for both theta and phi. My worry with making a struct for the points is an efficiency one. The actual code requires this to be done several hundred times and then I need to use these points to calculate a flux across the sphere.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the line:

```
std::cout << points[i][0] << " " << points[i][1] << " " << points[i][2] << "\n";
```

with (you also need to include `<limits>` and `<iomanip>`):

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10+2) << points[i][0] << " " << points[i][1] << " " << points[i][2] << "\n";
```

You'll see that the output is:

```
sorted points
0.00000000000000000 0.99999999999999978 1.00000000000000000
0.99999999999999989 0.99999999999999978 0.00000000000000000
1.00000000000000000 0.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000022
1.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000 2.00000000000000000
1.00000000000000000 2.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000
1.00000000000000000 2.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000
1.00000000000000022 0.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000
2.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000
duplicates removed 
0.00000000000000000 0.99999999999999978 1.00000000000000000
0.99999999999999989 0.99999999999999978 0.00000000000000000
1.00000000000000000 0.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000022
1.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000 2.00000000000000000
1.00000000000000000 2.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000
1.00000000000000022 0.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000
2.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000
```

So **considering approximations** the vector has been correctly sorted.

PS you could use a custom comparator in the `std::sort()` call and a custom binary predicate in the `std::unique` call.

Comment: So, do you think that will issue will be fixed, for example, by replacing `double` with `int`?

Comment: @Drop Yes, I think so (at least in the specific example).

Comment: Oh I get it! I had a feeling it was something to do with the approximation of PI. Okay so as I can't change to `int` as in the actual code I need every 10 degrees I will try as you suggest, thanks so much!!